# How do I limit my cubes fly-time in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So basically my intention was that my cube has the ability to jump but my code isn't good.

My code:

```
if(Input.GetKey("w"))
    rb.AddForce(0,UpwwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

My problem is that when I press <kbd>W</kbd> the cube just keeps going up? It doesnt stop going. I have been wrapping my head around it for a few hours and would love if someone could help me out.

Comment: This needs way more context

Comment: Okay so i am following brackeys example not his tutorial and i tried to use his principles to get an upward elevation instead of left and right basically what i need is a way for my input w to stop pushing my cube upwards after a specified threshold basically i need to limit how high its going

Comment: What is this cube you speak of? Who is brackey? How do your two lines of code fit into the project?

Comment: Oh those lines of code are used for the movemnt of the cube from the left to the right on the x axis I am trying to apply the same principle on the y axis but the i get the previously mentioned result